# Angular karma phantom before each hook error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-mocha

I am running my tests with karma and phantom, i am using mocha and sinon and sometimes the tests pass and sometimes without any reason i get this errors:

```
    ✖ "before each" hook: workFn
      ✔ should call get user api
  ✖ "after each" hook for "should call get user api"

Finished in 1.04 secs / 0.2 secs

SUMMARY:
✔ 42 tests completed
✖ 3 tests failed

FAILED TESTS:
  UserService
    ✖ "before each" hook: workFn
      PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)
    TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('.arrow' + index).classList') (public/client/build/main.js:3195)

  ✖ "after each" hook for "should call get user api"
    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)
    PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)
  TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.$injector')
      at public/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2229
```

What can cause to this problem?

Comment: didn't define a mock? It's hard to see what's wrong with the code without seeing the code...

Comment: The problem is when i reset karma it's working, I don't know what cause to this to fail from time to time.

Comment: Got the same bug with PhantomJS 2.0.0. It seems to be a angularMock related bug, downgrading it to 1.4.X seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I have this as well using Mocha, Sinon, and React.

Comment: This doesn't entirely solve my problem, but if I try karma-chrome-launcher I can't get my tests to fail in the same way no matter how many times I run them.

Comment: can you include karma configuration (karma.conf.js) ?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, DOM calls using Karma and/or PhantomJS can be a problem. The DOM in PhantomJS doesn't operate exactly like a standard browser and, as such, it tends to error on GUI operations a lot.

My advice (although it might not be the best) is to spy on or mock out the document methods you're using off of `document` since what they do is out of your hands anyways.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is clearly highlighted from the karma output, no?

`'document.querySelector('.arrow' + index).classList'`

it could not find on element by selector, so `classList` of undefined is null. You need to look into it.

Comment: The issue is that the tests are intermittent, and only when using PhantomJS.